# Conditional Expectation on Other Random Variable

Tags: probability, self-learning, conditional-expectation

I have a question on conditional expectation (I guess):

A message being sent over a communications network is assigned by a router to one of three paths (path 1, path 2, path 3). The nature of the network is such that

- 50% of all messages are routed to path 1,
- 30% are routed to path 2,
- and 20% are routed to path 3.

If routed to

- path **1**, then the message has a **75%** chance of reaching its destination immediately. Otherwise, the message experiences a **$5$-second delay** and returns to the router.
- path **2**, then the message has a **60%** chance of reaching its destination immediately. Otherwise, the message experiences a **$10$-second delay** and returns to the router.
- path **3**, then the message has a **40%** chance of reaching its destination immediately. Otherwise, the message experiences a **$20$-second delay** and returns to the router.

Note that the router cannot distinguish between new messages and messages that have returned from an unsuccessful attempt. Let $X$ denote the time until the message reaches its destination.

(a) Compute the expected value of X .

fot this part I guess that:

- P(Y= path 1) $= 0.5$,
- P(Y= path2 ) $= 0.3$ ,
- P(Y=path 3) $= 0.2$ ,
- E(X|Y=1)$ = 0.25 \times 5$  ,
- E(X|Y=2)$ = 0.4 \times 10$ ,
- E(X|Y=3)$ = 0.6 \times 20$

so  $E[X]= \sum_y \{ P(Y =y) \times E[X|Y=y] \}$

(b) Compute the standard deviation of X .

However for this problem, I think I need to get $E[X^2|Y=y]$ but I can't figure a way to do that. And is my modeling for part (a) correct?

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Your computations for part (a) describe features of the the time until the message reaches its destination or is back to the router while X is supposed to be the time until the message reaches its destination, obviously larger.

Comment: You have missed I think on part A, that the process is potentially infinite, the message can keep returning to the server (but each time having a probability of finishing).

If the process does wait, then return to the server, can you see what it's expected further time is FROM THAT POINT?  If you can, then you might see that 

E = (expected wait on one cycle) + P(returns to Server) x E 

so you could then get E

Comment: I think (b) - calculate VARIANCE of time delay on one attempt (start by calculating $E[x^2]$ for one attempt and subtract square of mean you already got.  Then you have to sum the variances to infinity, based on the probability of n attempts